# genealogytree with multiple marriages on both sides

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, genealogytree

Suppose A had child X with B and child Y with C. I know that `union` works to get this done:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\genealogytree[template=formal graph,
]
{child{
        g[id=a, tikz={xshift=9mm,yshift=0mm}]{A}
        union{
            p[id=b, tikz={xshift=-9mm,yshift=0mm}]{B}
            c[id=x]{X}
        }
        union{
            p[id=c]{C}
            c[id=y]{Y}
        }
    }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

(the shifts are to prevent intersections)

But what if B also had child Z with some D? what I'm doing right now is `add parent`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{article}
\usepackage[top=4.5cm, bottom=4.5cm, left=1cm, right=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\genealogytree[template=formal graph,
add parent = b to fam_B
]
{child[id=fam_A]{
        g[id=a, tikz={xshift=9mm,yshift=0mm}]{A}
        union{
            p[id=b, tikz={xshift=-9mm,yshift=0mm}]{B}
            c[id=x]{X}
        }
        union{
            p[id=c]{C}
            c[id=y]{Y}
        }
    }
child[id=fam_B, edges up = 1 of 4]{
    g[id=d, tikz={xshift=-15mm,yshift=0mm}] {D}
    c[id=z, tikz={xshift=-9mm,yshift=0mm}] {Z}}
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This produces

[image]

which is great except the edges only come out of B at one spot (compare with the two edges coming out of A). I can't seem to find a way to adjust the edge start points, just the central nodes.

Is there a way to do this nicely? I'm hoping for something generalizable to more than two marriages on each side (with copious amounts of shifts).

Answer (score 1):

One way is to color each node and highlight wife2 and the progeny with green -- and color wife3 and progeny in blue -- tracing is easier -- off course the edges can also be segregated based on color

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{article}
\usepackage[top=4.5cm, bottom=4.5cm, left=1cm, right=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \genealogytree[template=formal graph,
        % add parent = b to fam_B
        options for node={wife2, childw2}{box={colback=green!20!white}},
        options for node={wife3, childw3}{box={colback=blue!20!white}},
        ]{
        
        child{
                g[male]{Husband}
                p[female]{Wife1}
                    c[female]{childw1}
                    % c[male]{a_4}
                    % c[female]{a_5}
                    union[id=fam_2]{
                                    p[id=wife2,female]{Wife2}
                                        c[id=childw2,female]{childw2}
                                        % c[id=nd3,male]{d_3}
                                        % c[id=nd4,male]{d_4}
                                    }

                    union[id=fam_3]{
                                    p[id=wife3,female]{Wife3}
                                        c[id=childw3,female]{childw3}
                                        % c[id=nd3,male]{d_3}
                                        % c[id=nd4,male]{d_4}
                                    }
                }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**With custom edges**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{article}
\usepackage[top=4.5cm, bottom=4.5cm, left=1cm, right=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \genealogytree[template=formal graph,
        % add parent = b to fam_B
        options for node={wife2, childw2}{box={colback=green!20!white}},
        options for node={wife3, childw3}{box={colback=blue!20!white}},
        ]{
        
        child{
                g[male]{Husband}
                p[female]{Wife1}
                    c[female]{childw1}
                    union[id=fam_2, family={edges={foreground={green!30}}}]{
                                    p[id=wife2,female, ]{Wife2}
                                        c[id=childw2,female]{childw2}
                                    }

                    union[id=fam_3, family={edges={foreground={blue!30,}}}]{
                                    p[id=wife3,female,]{Wife3}
                                        c[id=childw3,female]{childw3}
                                    }
                }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This does help distinguish children from different marriages, but I am hoping to adjust the edges so that previous marriages of both the husband and the wife will have separate edges.